# Cancelling MFMailComposeViewController causes a memory leak?

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I use MFMailComposeViewController in an app I'm working on now. When user taps on a button, email form pops up.

Now when I use instruments to monitor memory during this process I see that  every time you push the cancel button and the action sheet appears, about 2.5 mb of memory adds up to live bytes in all heap & anonymous vm. This only occurs if you tap the cancel button, everything runs normally when you send the email.

Btw I checked Apple's MessageComposer sample code [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/MessageComposer/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010161) , it has the same issue.

Does anyone know what might be the reason?

Comment: Got the same problem right here. This seems like a massive leak, very odd that it's not being taken care of.

Comment: I have the same issue and wounded up here.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a memory leak in the API (UIKit) - they are rare but they certainly do occur, I remember reporting one back in SDK 4.0 which occured when running the standard 'Masterview Controller' template.